# R Moving Yahoo Fantasy API from Oauth 1 to Oauth2

Tags: r, yahoo-api

It appears that Yahoo has discontinued support for oauth1.0. I am trying to update my R code to use oauth2.0 using the httr package, and am stumped. I am able to get token, but am unable to use the token to query the api.

I continue to get "You are not authorized to view this league".

```
options("httr_oob_default" = T)
library(httr)

b_url <- "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com" #base url

#Create Endpoint
yahoo <- httr::oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth"
                                       , access = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token"
                                       , base_url = b_url)
#Create App
yahoo_app <- httr::oauth_app("yahoo", key=cKey, secret = cSecret,redirect_uri = "oob")

#Open Browser to Authorization Code
httr::BROWSE(httr::oauth2.0_authorize_url(yahoo, yahoo_app, scope="fspt-r"
                                          , redirect_uri = yahoo_app$redirect_uri))
#Code = zp6v82a

#Create Token
yahoo_token<- httr::oauth2.0_access_token(yahoo,yahoo_app,code="zp6v82a")
```

Now im not sure where to go from here.

If there is any advice, or an easier method please let me know. I am an amateur coder so please, be gentle.

Comment: Quick question, where did you get the code when Yahoo asks for it? I am able to reproduce the code using my own league info and app but can't figure out where the 7-digit code gets generated when asked by Yahoo for the authorization code. Any clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: turns out it was an issue with the HTTR package. I believe it has been fixed since. but to answer your question, a browser should open with the code, and you add it to the last bit code. this is a one time deal if you save the token. if that's not working for you, i did use this fork to get my results https://github.com/ctrombley/httr

Comment: Thanks. I received the authorization code but I still get the "You are not authorized to view this league" message whenever I try to query. Have you gotten past that message?